# Remove a specific inline element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove a specific inline style that is added by a JS. I have been working around with this sample. Unfortunately still not successful.

```
<a id="mylink" style="color:red; font-weight:bold" 
href="http://www.website.com">go to somesite.com</a>
```

My requirement, I want to remove the 'font-weight:bold' using jquery.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("mylink").style.removeAttribute('font-weight:bold'); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeAttribute` won't work, as `font-weight: bold` is a style and not an attribute. To remove/unset this, I would suggest using [`CSSStyleDeclaration.removeProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty):

```
document.getElementById("mylink").style.removeProperty("font-weight")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('mylink').style.fontWeight = "100"
```

Comment: How can I remove that property from the style

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery:

```
$('#mylink').css('font-weight','');
```

Comment: @Chris, cheers for the edit, I'm amazed by the accepted answer, given that they asked for a jquery solution :D